# how to invite facebook friends in asp.net application using facebook javascript sdk with iframe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbml, facebook-iframe

`<% if (!IsFaceBookConnected)`

`{%>`
 
`<script>`
`FB.init('APP_ID', '<%= Settings.RootUrl %>XdReceiver.aspx');`
`</script>`

`<%else{ %>`

`<div style="padding:0px;width:100%;">`

`<div id="fb-root">`
   `<fb:serverfbml style="width:100%">`
       
`<script type="text/fbml">`
          
 `<fb:fbml>`
          
 `<fb:request-form
                    action="invite-friends" 
                    method="post" 
                    type="Invite" 
                    content="">`
     
  `<fb:multi-friend-selector max="25" showborder="false" actiontext="Invite Friends" email_invite="false" bypass="cancel" />`
          
 `</fb:request-form>`
         
  `</fb:fbml>`
       
 `</script>`
   
 `</fb:serverfbml>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`
    
`FB.init({`
       
`apiKey: 'XXXXX',`
       
`appId: 'XXXXX',`
      
 `status: true, // check login status`
      
 `cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session<br/>`
      
  `xfbml: true  // parse XFBML`
  
 `});`
 
 `FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);`
 `function handleSessionResponse(response)`
       `FB.XFBML.parse(); }`

`</script>`
`<%} %>`

`http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=XXXXXXXX&xfbml=1`

I want to invite facebook friends through fbml. But it is not loading facebook friend's list.Some days before it is working fine through fbml.How to do that?

Comment: http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js – don’t know where you got that address from, but it doesn’t deliver any content, but only a 403 forbidden. The right address to embed the JS SDK is the one you find in the docs.

Comment: @CBroe, I have corrected the above link. But still now I could not find the solution. If you know about it, tell me.